# CSS transparent colour overlay fade not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch

I have made a grid of images and when you hover over them a semi-transparent overlay fades in and out and some text appears

I wanted this to work similarly on mobile devices, only instead of it fading in when you hover, it fades in when you tap

I have managed to get this working on android but not on mobiles.

I will show my code and a few examples of solutions I have tried. I have tried so many but I am rather new to javascript (I have some functioning javascript working on my site though!) and nothing is working on iOS devices.

Js fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/49h450g9/

I am using bootstrap and less. My grid HTML code:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5"><div class="image-wrap">

<img src="assets/images/image1.jpg">
<div class="overlay purple2">
<br>
    <h3>image 1</h3>
    <hr>
      <p>description</p>
      <br>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-lg">View Website</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><div class="image-wrap">
<img src="assets/images/image2.jpg">

    <div class="overlay blue">
    <h3>image 2</h3>
    <hr>
      <p>description</p>
      <br>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-lg">View Website</a>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><div class="image-wrap">
<img src="assets/images/image4.jpg">
<div class="overlay purple1">
    <h3>image 3</h3>
    <hr>
      <p>description</p>
      <br>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-lg">View Website</a>
    </div>

</div>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-7"><div class="image-wrap">
<img src="assets/images/image5.jpg">
<div class="overlay blue">
    <h3>image 5</h3>
    <hr>
      <p><strong>description</p>
      <br>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-lg">View Website</a>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5"><div class="image-wrap">
<img src="assets/images/image6.jpg">
<div class="overlay purple2">
    <h3>Image 6</h3>
    <hr>
      <p>description</p>
      <br>
      <a href="about-us.php" class="btn btn-white btn-lg">View Website</a>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>

    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-wrap {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;  
}
.overlay {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color:white;
opacity: 0;
transition:opacity .5s ease-out;
text-align: center;
hr {
border: 1px solid #fff;
width: 10%;
 }

}

.image-wrap:hover .overlay {
opacity: 1;
}

.red {
background: rgba(102,67,154,0.7);
}

.blue {
background: rgba(23,56,179,0.7);
}
.purple1 {
background: rgba(140,23,179,0.7);
}

.purple2 {
background: rgba(71,13,142,0.7);
}
```

Solutions I have tried include:

1. adding

   onclick=""

to the image wrap div element

2 adding the JS line to my js file:

```
$('body').bind('touchstart', function() {});
```

3. Adding the following js to my js file:

2 adding the JS line to my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".overlay").hover(function(){
//On Hover - Works on ios
$("p").hide();
}, function(){
//Hover Off - Hover off doesn't seem to work on iOS
$("p").show();
})
});
```

However, on iOS none of my solutions are working, when I tap no text or semi-transparent overlay fades in

I have been working on this for nearly a week and have looked at many questions on here but I cannot find a solution that works for me

Any help would be massively appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `:active` pseudo class instead of `:hover`. In touch mobile devices, once an hover is triggered, it will not get removed once you take your finger off. It need you to tap on somewhere else on the screen.

similarly in jquery you can use `mousedown()` and `mouseup()` for the same purpose. on `mousedown()` you may show the overlay and `mouseup()` you may hide it.

Comment: I changed this one 
.image-wrap:active .overlay {
opacity: 1;
} 
and is working for me

Comment: on iOS? on my phone it is still not working, I changed exactly this

Comment: are you using any of my js solutions too?

Comment: I'm not checking from real device. I am checking from chrome ipad simulator. But generally it behave same as device.

Comment: I used mousedown(); mouseup(); solutions in some rare cases and they where working fine for me.

Comment: I was using the chrome ipad simulator too, I got excited, test on my actual iphone and neither mine nor your solution will work. Yeah it definitely doesn't work on an iphone, thanks for your help though :)

Comment: My js is limited I am unsure how to apply the mouseup() solution, do you know anywhere there is an example please?

Comment: strange! le tme try whether I can share a fiddle

Comment: yeah I thought that, usually works well! it works on andriod mobiles just note iOS despite working in tests, only when I actually use it on an iphone there is a problem, I put a js fiddle above somewhere too

Comment: hey, this works on my andriod and touch screen laptop but not my iphone! Same with my js fiddle at the start of my question, think it needs some better js code, mine doesn't work on iphones either

Comment: rather than checking the fiddle, can you paste the code in a fresh HTML file and test? In the mean time, I will share another fiddle with jquery.

Comment: Thank you, this doesn't work on the iphone either, I might try and implement your mouseup and mousedown jquery code though with my js fiddle, maybe it will work!

Comment: it does flash grey for a split second though, maybe this is working..?!

Comment: I wanted it to fade in and either slowly out again or not until somewhere else is tapped

Comment: in css method, you may use css transition. may be use an opacity transition. On jquery, you may just replace show(); hide(); with fadeIn(); fadeOut();

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try and apply my css transition and text overlay with yours, thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160766/discussion-between-pons-purushothaman-and-ck777).

Comment: hey, I have to pop out but here is my jsfiddle using your technique, https://jsfiddle.net/49h450g9/4/ it works on my laptop and all touchscreen devices apart from iphones!